# Getting ERRORS while Creating a new Defect in Rally using python

Tags: python, rally

Following is my code to add new defect to rally using python:

```
import sys import time from pyral import Rally, rallyWorkset
server = "rally1.rallydev.com" 
user = "*****" 
password = "****" 
apikey = "****" 
workspace = "****" 
project = "****"
rally = Rally(server, user=user, password=password,apikey=apikey, workspace=workspace, project=project)

project_req = rally.get('Project', fetch=True, query='Name = "%s"' % (project))
project = project_req.next()

priority = "3.Normal" 
severity = "Major Problem" 
name = "prabhakar.sharma@***.com"
#defectID = 'INC0547865'
description = "A Test Rally User Story created using python API now, start working on it as fast as you all could !!" 
user = rally.getUserInfo(username=name).pop(0)
#rally.setProject(proj) 
print("%s %s "% (project.oid , user.ref)) 
defect_data = { "Project" : project.ref,
                "SubmittedBy" : user.ref,
                "Name" : name,
                "Severity" : severity, 
                "Priority" : priority,
               "State" : "Open", 
                "ScheduleState" : "Defined",
                "Owner": user.ref,
                "Description" : description 
                }


defect = rally.create('Defect', defect_data) print("Defect created, ObjectID: %s  FormattedID: %s" % (defect.oid, defect.FormattedID))
```

Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "pythonrally.py", line 186,
>   in 
>       defect = rally.create('Defect', defect_data)   File "C:\Users\PRABHAKAR.SHARMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\pyral\restapi.py",
>   line 1024, in put
>       raise RallyRESTAPIError(problem) pyral.restapi.RallyRESTAPIError: 422 Validation error: Defect.PRJ# should not be null

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rally, and I can't quickly locate this method in the documentation; but it clearly tells you that the input you are providing to the `create` method is not valid. It apparently expects something different, perhaps wrapped in an object rather than a `dict`?

Answer (score 0):

Changes:

1. Must use "username=name" (where 'name' is a login ID) instead of "username=user".
2. The field "When" is not part of a Defect (commented out below).
3. The field "PRJ#" is not part of a Defect (commented out below).
4. The project ref must be specified as "proj.ref" instead of "project.ref".

   ```
   $ diff code.orig code.new
   10c10
   < user = rally.getUserInfo(username=user).pop(0)
   ---
   > user = rally.getUserInfo(username=name).pop(0)
   12,14c12,14
   < defect_data = { "When" : when,
   <                 "PRJ#" : project.oid,
   <                 "Project" : project.ref,
   ---
   > defect_data = { #"When" : when,
   >                 #"PRJ#" : proj.oid,
   >                 "Project" : proj.ref,
   ```

The above changes worked for me.

Comment: Hey @JPKole , I am glad that worked for you but I am still struggling. I did the changes you mentioned above too. Is there still anything i am missing maybe theoretically or code-wise !! I updated the question above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, I changed below line :

```
defect = rally.create('Defect', defect_data) print("Defect created, ObjectID: %s  FormattedID: %s" % (defect.oid, defect.FormattedID))
```

to

```
defect = rally.create('UserStory', defect_data) print("Defect created, ObjectID: %s  FormattedID: %s" % (defect.oid, defect.FormattedID))
```

and following what errors were telling me I got it working.
Also, I removed few fields from 'defect_data' as following:

```
defect_data = { "Project" : project.ref,
                #"SubmittedBy" : user.ref,
                "Name" : name,
                #"Severity" : severity, 
                "Priority" : priority,
                #"State" : "Open", 
                "ScheduleState" : "Defined",
                "Owner": user.ref,
                "Description" : description 
                }
```

Final Code:

```
project_req = rally.get('Project', fetch=True, query='Name = "%s"' % (project))
project = project_req.next()
priority = "Normal"
severity = "Major Problem"
name = "prabhakar.sharma@dish.com"
#when = "2018.12.26 - 2019.01.01"
#defectNum = 'INC0547865'
description = "Just one more test Rally User Story created using python API now, start working on it as fast as you all could !!"
user = rally.getUserInfo(username=user).pop(0)
#rally.setProject(proj)
print("%s %s "% (project.ref , user.ref))
defect_data = { "Project" : project.ref,
                #"SubmittedBy" : user.ref,
                "Name" : name,
                #"Severity" : severity, 
                "Priority" : priority,
                #"State" : "Open", 
                "ScheduleState" : "Defined",
                "Owner": user.ref,
                "Description" : description 
                }
try:
    print("am here %s "% defect_data)
    defect = rally.create('UserStory', defect_data)
except Exception as e:
    sys.stderr.write('ERROR: %s \n' % Exception)
    print(e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Hope this serves someone facing any problem like this one !! Cheers